# Thai culture date gets converted twice

Tags: reactjs

```
export const lastUpdated = createSelector(
  learningDetails,
  ld =>
  {
    (ld.lastModifiedDate) &&
    Intl.DateTimeFormat('th-TH', {
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric',
    }).format(new Date(ld.lastModifiedDate))
  } 
);//returns >> 3107-05-21
```

Above is a function where the last update date is being picked up, since the ld.lastModifiedDate received from service is already in Thai time-zone by formatting the date value, it again gets converted.
For eg.:

Original date : 2021-05-21 in UTC
Converted on the the service layer to Thai time-zone to 2564-05-21 i.e. 543 years ahead (as Thai culture follows Buddhist calendar).
Service returns & populates ld.lastModifiedDate to 2564-05-21 which then gets formatted using Intl.DateTimeFormat as per culture this leads to bump up of the year again by 543 years. (2021+543+543) which is incorrect. Is there a dynamic way to avoid the second time conversion for all cultures irrespectively along with formatting.

Note: We can't change the legacy service layer to return UTC/original date as it is being invoked by other internal functions.

Comment: There is no C# in this question, why is the tag there?

Comment: Apologies, removed it..

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution from : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat

Basically, by appending '-u-ca-gregory' to the culture solves the issue.
Default considering Gregorian calendar.

```
export const lastUpdated = createSelector(
  learningDetails,
  ld =>
  {
    (ld.lastModifiedDate) &&
    Intl.DateTimeFormat('th-TH-u-ca-gregory', {
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      year: 'numeric',
    }).format(new Date(ld.lastModifiedDate))
  } 
);//returns >> 2564-05-21
```